# Excel formula , negate records based on date and type and retrieve unique rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excelsheet with several rows and columns of data , important columns being
Company Name, Date of Transaction , Type of Transaction , Transaction amount. 
Type of Transacation can be deposit or withdrawal. Now I want to negate(delete) all those 
rows of records where the deposit and withdrawal are same amount on the same date for the same company. For example

```
Company Name | Date of Trans | Type of Trans | Trans Amount

ABC          | 1 Jan 2020    | Dep           | 100

ABC          | 1 Jan 2020    | Dep           | 200

ABC          | 1 Jan 2020    | Wit           |-100

ABC          | 2 Jan 2020    | wit           |-500 

DEF          | 10 Jan 2020   | Dep           | 200

DEF          | 10 Jan 2020   | Wit           |-200

XYZ          | 1 Jan 2020    | Dep           | 500

ABC          | 3 Jan 2020    | Dep           | 500
```

End result should look like

```
Company Name | Date of Trans | Type of Trans | Trans Amount

ABC          | 1 Jan 2020    | Dep       | 200

ABC          | 2 Jan 2020    | wit       |-500 

ABC          | 3 Jan 2020    | Dep       | 500

XYZ          | 1 Jan 2020    | Dep       | 500
```

What I have done so far is

1)Concatenate Company name, date of trans and absolute(amount)

2) Sort the dataset based on above Ascending

3) Form an IF statement (check top row, bottom row) on 2 columns for data in step 2

4) Then another if statement (check top row, bottom row) on 2 columns to check on type of transaction type.

But this doesn't work as Type of transaction doesn't necessarily come as `DEP-WIT-DEP-WIT` in that pattern and date of transaction for same company can be different.

Requesting help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in Col A:D then in E2:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,IF(C2="Dep","Wit","Dep"),D:D,-D2)
```

[image]

Comment: that formula populates cells from E2 down with 0 in all the rows. Confirmation: my data is in A:D with headers.

Comment: Works for me - see screenshot

Comment: Thanks for the excellent formula Tim. However it is failing on this scenario, please see the rows marked in red. Ideally those should have come as 0 as they are 2 unique deposit transactions (they do not have any Wit transactions on that date to offset). I don't see an option to attach screenshot , please find the screenshot in an external link here - https://imgur.com/zGfQSA3

Comment: You didn't describe how you intend to handle cases where there are multiple possible matches. The formula's not really "failing" - there are two other rows in your dataset which could pair with either of your two highlighted rows and so it reports those counts.  You will always need to make a selection in cases of multiple matches

Comment: Thank you again Tim. I agree, I will have to make a selection in cases of there are multiple deposits of same amount (on same date) with one or more offsetting withdrawal.

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround for the case that OP mentioned is to compare the number of matching transactions so far with the total number of matching opposite transactions (i.e. same amount, date and company but wit instead of dep or dep instead of wit)

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,B2,C$2:C2,C2,D$2:D2,D2)>COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,IF(C2="Dep","Wit","Dep"),D:D,-D2),"keep","delete")
```

[image]

The Same and Opposite columns are just included as a check

Comment: Fantastic Tom. I cross checked your formula and it is working perfectly. Thank you for the addition, I really appreciate.